Stream map over classes with Lombok SuperBuilder
Class MyEntity extends a base class. Both have lombok's (version 1.18.34) @SuperBuilder annotation.
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    public abstract SomeType getSomeType();
}

@Value
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Override
    public SomeType getSomeType() {
        return SomeType.SOMETHING;
    }
}

If I try to map something to MyEntity like so
someItems.stream()
    .map(item -> MyEntity.builder().build())
    .toList();

The return type of this is List<?>. Why does the compiler fail to infer the type here? If I look at the build() method I do see a generic public abstract C build().
As a workaround, I can move the build to a separate method.
private MyEntity getBuild(SomeItem item) {
    return MyEntity.builder().build();
}


List<MyEntity> myEntities = someItems.stream() // works
    .map(item -> getBuild(item))
    .toList();

EDIT
I took the classes I brought as example and created this example method. The type of the map list is List<?>
public static List<MyEntity> doSomething(List<String> strings) 
{
    List<?> list = strings.stream().map(s -> MyEntity.builder().build()).toList();
    return (List<MyEntity>) list;
}

Take a look at these:
public static List<MyEntity> creatingTheEntityFirst() {
    MyEntity build = MyEntity.builder().build();
    return List.of(build);
}

public static List<MyEntity> creatingEntityInAList(List<String> strings) {
    List<?> build = List.of(MyEntity.builder().build()); // type is List<?>
    return build; // this would error because provided is List<?>
    return List.of(MyEntity.builder().build()); // however this works
}


The type of the expression is not List<?>. What gave you that idea? It is List<T> where T is a captured type extending MyEntity.

Type of the variable for the .map(..).toList(), I got type List<?>

I cannot reproduce that. Can you assign the result to a variable of type List<? extends MyEntity>? If you can, that means whatever you are using to look at the variable's type is incorrect.

The return type of the toList call is not List<?>, but List<T> where T is a fresh type variable with upper bound MyEntity. This means that you can assign it to a variable of type List<? extends MyEntity>.
// this compiles
List<? extends MyEntity> result = someItems.stream()
    .map(item -> MyEntity.builder().build())
    .toList();

The reason this happens is because builder() returns a MyEntityBuilder<?, ?>. Importantly, the first type parameter of this (the type C that is also the return type of build) is a wildcard, so we know nothing about C except that it inherits from MyEntity. MyEntityBuilder<?, ?> then undergoes capture conversion and the first ? becomes a fresh type variable with upper bound MyEntity. Let's call the fresh type variable T.
This means that build would return T. So map returns a Stream<T>, and toList returns a List<T>.
Since T has an upper bound of MyEntity, it is possible to convert T to MyEntity. But your code never does that before the T gets put into list, at which point it is no longer possible to do that implicitly (List<? extends MyEntity> is not a subtype of List<MyEntity>).
You can do that T -> MyEntity conversion earlier, in the map lambda:
List<MyEntity> result = someItems.stream()
        .map(item -> (MyEntity)MyEntity.builder().build())
        .toList();


You might be wondering why builder is declared to return MyEntityBuilder<?, ?> as opposed to MyEntityBuilder<MyEntity, ?>. This is because the language rules simply does not allow this (JLS 8.4.8.3). Consider a concrete super class X and a concrete subclass Y, both having @SuperBuilder.
The two classes would both end up having a builder method. X.builder would return XBuilder<X, ?> and B.builder would return YBuilder<Y, ?>. These are not return-type-substitutable methods.
In your case, since the superclass is abstract, and lombok doesn't generate the builder method, it is possible for the subclass's builder to return MyEntityBuilder<MyEntity, ?>:
@SuperBuilder
class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Override
    public SomeType getSomeType() {
        return SomeType.SOMETHING;
    }

    public static MyEntityBuilder< MyEntity, ?> builder() {
        return new MyEntityBuilderImpl();
    }
}

Of course, this will not work if MyEntity has @SuperBuilder subclasses of its own.

Thanks for the detailed explanation!
Using List<? extends MyEntity> complies, but as I want to return this list from a function with return type List<MyEntity>, I have to use the current workaround or do the cast in the .map(). Otherwise, error Required type: List <MyEntity>, Provided:List<? extends MyEntity>

I added more examples. Can you recreate any?

@syydi The type of an expression is different from "what type of variables you can assign it to". Just because you can assign it to List<?> doesn't mean that the type of the expression is List<?>. In fact, the type of a method call can never be List<?>, because capture conversion always happens. Please see the very end of this section of the JLS. I'll repeat this again, the type of the toList() call is List<T> where T is a captured type variable with upper bound MyEntity.

Thank you, I understand. I was just confused when you said that you cannot recreate it. I thought you don't see the List<?>.

@syydi I thought you were using some kind of IDE feature that shows you what type something is. e.g. In IntelliJ, you can do View -> Type Info.
